# Proof for $\cos(\alpha)^2 + \cos(\beta)^2 + \cos(\gamma)^2 = 1$ in Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

What is the proof for this formula: 
$$
\cos(\alpha)^2 + \cos(\beta)^2 + \cos(\gamma)^2 = 1,
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the angles between a vector and the base of a right-handed orthonormal base in Euclidean space? I can't seem to find a solid proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Use the inner/dot  product interpretation of these angles. Then the statement becomes immediate.

Comment: You mean, $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{\mathbf{V}_1 \cdot \mathbf{V}_2}{|\mathbf{V}_1|*|\mathbf{V}_2|}$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between V1 and V2?

Comment: Except it is dot product not cross product.

Comment: yes, corrected it